# mysql view query unidentified issue

Tags: mysql

Does anybody see what is wrong in this query?
i have been trying many different things and i can't get it right

```
SELECT h.guru_or_guru_user_id,
        (
            (0.25 * (s.total_pips/sr.highest_total_pips)) +
            (0.2 * (s.total_gain/sr.highest_total_gain)) +
            (0.15 * (sr.lowest_volatility/s.volatility)) +
            (0.05 * (s.running_weeks/sr.most_running_weeks)) +
            (0.15 * (s.total_trades/sr.most_total_trades)) +
            (0.2 * (s.average_profit_loss_ratio/sr.highest_average_profit_loss_ratio))
        ) AS guru_score
from gt_view_mt_stats as s 
inner join gt_history as h
    on s.login = h.login
    and h.is_guru_history = 1
left join gt_view_stats_records as sr
group by h.guru_or_guru_user_id
order by guru_score desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
left join gt_view_stats_records as sr
```

By removing the `left join` and add it as a normally:

```
.....
 and h.is_guru_history = 1,
 gt_view_stats_records as sr
....
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick syntax check gives the following error:

```
group(15,1) expected token:ON JOIN
```

Line 15 is the line starting with `GROUP BY` and immediately preceding that is a `LEFT JOIN`, but you don't have an `ON` condition for the join - hence the error "expected token: ON".

You'll have to update the query to include the `ON` condition for the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
...
left join gt_view_stats_records as sr
    ON sr.some_key = other_key
group by h.guru_or_guru_user_id
```

Comment: thank u :))))) but i really don't have some key to put on the "on" condition... any other suggestements?

Comment: @user502967 You are attempting to *join* against a table named `gt_view_stats_records`, which I'm assuming contains stats/records which normally consists of a lot of data; if these records really don't associate with the ones you're selecting, what is the purpose of selecting them in your query (especially considering you don't have a `WHERE` clause)?

Comment: @user502967 Not to hold you back from getting your code working, if you *really* want to do a full-join (without a condition), you can change `LEFT JOIN` to just `JOIN` and it will work fine without a condition; however, I'd still suggest reviewing the "need" to do this as it can return a lot of data that may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

All fields except guru_or_guru_user_id are not in group by clause and not encapsulated in aggregate function, so MySql get the first value, the result you want can be different than real result.

So, you use LEFT OUTER JOIN so, it possible SR field can be NULL, so your expression can be corrupted by this unmanaged value.

After LEFT OUTER JOIN where's the clause ON?